# What's the programing language of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

For me, Stack Exchange is the best thing since [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail), and I want to know more about Stack Exchange. What's the programing language of Stack Exchange?

Comment: So you plan to learn it as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, sir, I think interests are best teachers.

Comment: Knowing C# won't help you understand SE at all, since the code isn't public.

Comment: ASP.net, C# , .NET, JavaScript & derivatives, some networking stuff. just learn ALL . ALL IS GOOD